# Conditional Formatting for Spreadsheet Cells based on Time Value (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: libreoffice, time

I want the highlight the cells in libreoffice which is time filled in the cell is more than 9:00:00.

I tried `format-> conditional formatting->condition`.

I get the cells highlighted based on single value but i didn't get how to highlight the cell with time based.

I tried TIMEVALUE but cells doesn't highlight, see the pic..

[image]

I did any thing wrong, give comment

Comment: oh shut!!! i missed semi column.... it's working nice .. NOW

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [**`TIMEVALUE()`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/TIMEVALUE) function to convert the time string `09:00:00` into a time value that LO can use for comparison (*if you're using a different localization than English, you may have to translate the function name accordingly - for the localized name, follow [this link](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/TIMEVALUE) and select the appropriate language from the language bar at the top of the help page*). So, just use "`Cell value is`" -> "`greater than`" -> "`TIMEVALUE("09:00:00")`" as condition:

[image]

<sup>*(Screenshot from LO Calc 5.0.1.2)*</sup>

Comment: i did it, but it cant works.... how to add picture in comments... i want to show what i did .?

Comment: just edit your question. If this doesn't work, put the screenshot online and add the url in a comment or in your original question.

Comment: @manikanta: My answer assumes english localisation. If you're using a differently localised version of LO, you will have to "translate" the formula name, too. For example, the name of the TIMEVALUE function in portugese is [VALOR.TEMPO](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/TIMEVALUE/pt-BR), and in spanish [HORANÚMERO](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/TIMEVALUE/es). Just follow the link in my answer behind the word TIMEVALUE and select the appropriate language in the language bar at the top of the libreoffice help page.